# Android - Application Level socket.io

Tags: android, sockets, design-patterns, socket.io

I'm working with Socket, using Socket.io Android Library & it's implemented well and working successfully.
It's done, But it's in only single activity.

Now I want socket implementation in the entire application.
Something more reliable and easy.
I need socket listeners and methods to emit and receive in a single place so don't have to write everywhere.

I want a class where I can put all socket code and access it from anywhere and listen to that class all the time & pass an event to other Activities or Fragment if I receive anything in a socket.

What should be a good solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should try moving your SocketIO implementation to a Service, it looks like the right use case to do it.

here you can find a post on how to implement it and do the communication activity/service 
[Ways to communicate between activity and service](https://medium.com/@ankit_aggarwal/ways-to-communicate-between-activity-and-service-6a8f07275297)

Comment: Note: If your app targets API level 26 or higher, the system imposes restrictions on running background services when the app itself isn't in the foreground. In most cases like this, your app should use a scheduled job instead.